# how would I have the image in this div with rollover not get the overlay?

Tags: html, css

was wondering how I would have the white chat bubble escape the overlay.

if there is also any way to simplify whats happening here with this code that would be appreciated too, I'm sure this is over the top.

thanks!

HTML

```
<a href="#">
<span class="rollover-button"></span>
<div class="the-button"><div class="innerbox"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSFeU.png"></div><p>some link</p></div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
.rollover-button {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: #2570B0;
    height: 29px;
    width: 175px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}

.rollover-button:hover {
     opacity: .6;
}

.the-button {
    background-color: #B5B3BE;
    width: 175px;
    height:29px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
}

.the-button p {
    position: absolute;
    right: 35px;
    top: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}

.innerbox {
    width: 29px;
    height: 29px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #5D6C6B;
}

.innerbox img {
     margin: 2px;
     width: 25px;
     height: 25px;
     z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Make  a fiddle at jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `z-index` property [only applies to positioned elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#layers).

Therefore if you want the chat bubble to appear over the other elements you would have to position it. (i.e., add `position: relative`), then increase the `z-index` value in this case.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ya1mgfft/)

```
.innerbox img {
    margin: 2px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    z-index: 20;          /* Increased from 1 -> 20 */
    position: relative;   /* Added this.. */
}
```

The default value of the `position` property is `static`, which is why it wasn't working.