# z-index has no effect div gets covered on jquery move

Tags: jquery, html, css, z-index

So I'm making a checkers game using jquery and when I move a piece it is visible on every cell before and above the square that the piece starts on but goes under any square after. I am using a game board with a flex row wrap display like this:

```
.board{
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   margin: 0 auto;
   z-index: 2;
}
```

the board contains 64 `.cell` divs and the `.piece` divs are placed inside those like so:

```
<div class="board">
 <cell>
  <piece>
 </cell>
 <cell>
 ...
```

The `z-index` of the pieces are greater than the cells which are greater than the board but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Is there an easy fix for this that I am missing? Perhaps something to do with flex display?

Should I move the piece div out of the cell and into the board div on move or perhaps keep all the pieces in the board div to begin with and assign their position dynamically?

Both of these options seem okay (more inclined towards the former) but I'm wondering why the `z-index` has no effect and if there is an attribute that I might be able to change to get the desired effect.

Comment: Try positioning the element (i.e., add `position: relative` to it). [The `z-index` property only applies to positioned elements.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27892184/2680216)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Z-index property does not work until you use any position property.
you have to set position first.

you can use any one position here as relative or fixed or absolute depends on your expected output.

```
.board{
       display: flex;
       flex-flow: row wrap;
       margin: 0 auto;
       z-index: 2;
       position: relative;
       position: fixed;
       position: absolute;
    }
```

Comment: all 3 positions at once? thats so gosu^^

Comment: I just provide him the most common 3 position example. Any one property could use here. And i have already told  why the z-index not working.

Comment: yeah sure, i know that;-) but explain that in the text only, and make the code without errors.

Comment: I think this is probably the right solution but I can't seem to solve the problem. I've tried as many different combinations of absolute positioning that I can think of but to no avail. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfaj4gbh/) I can't add the html as it's all dynamically generated. _shrug_ I guess I'll try moving in up a level on move and see if that doesn't work. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Without html-codig its very hard to guess what's going wrong in your code

Comment: understood I will go ahead and accept your answer as I guess my problem is occurring elsewhere and your answer to my question is correct.

Comment: putting it into the board '.div' solved the problem as was fairly easy to implement. Thanks for trying.